# node.js as localhost and use gulp to watch changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I cloned a repo here https://github.com/willianjusten/bootstrap-boilerplate and do the following step.

```
git clone git://github.com/willianjusten/bootstrap-boilerplate.git new_project
cd bootstrap-boilerplate
npm install
gulp
```

The gulp does the work. But is the server started? In gulp js file I'm seeing the author use livereload, how do I start my development with that?

Comment: According to the description the server should be running at port 8080. Did you try accessing `http://localhost:8080/`? Depending on your firewall you might have to whitelist the node executable to act as a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodemon (https://github.com/remy/nodemon). If any file is changed, nodemon will re-start automatically.

***Sample usage***

1. install

   npm install -g nodemon
2. start node

   nodemon server.js

Comment: Hi @AlienXu,
You don't need to use gulp to watch changes, nodemon can do that job for you.